# How to create transactional DAOs using JDBC

Tags: java, jdbc, transactions, dao

I'm working with JDBC now and want to create separate layers for data access and business logic. I've created several DAOs for each entity and several services for my business logics. But I faced a problem with transactions. In each DAO I have CRUD where I open connection in each operation and after close it. But if I need to use several operations like in transaction it won't work.

So I create one connection for whole DAO but I need to open and close connection for each operation outside DAO.

**Example of my DAO**

```java
public class UserDAOImpl implements UserDAO {

    private Connection connection;

    public UserDAO(Connection connection) {
        this.connection = connection;
    }

    // CRUD operations
}
```

**Abstract DAO Factory**

```java
public abstract class DAOFactory {

    public abstract UserDAO getUserDAO();
    public abstract ItemDAO getItemDAO();
    public abstract OrderDAO getOrderDAO();
    public abstract RoleDAO getRoleDAO();

    public static DAOFactory getDAOFactory(Class<? extends DAOFactory> factoryClass) throws IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException {
        return factoryClass.newInstance();
    }
}
```

**Example of implementation of MySQL DAO factory**

```java
public class MySqlDAOFactory extends DAOFactory {

    private UserDAO userDAO;
    private ItemDAO itemDAO;
    private OrderDAO orderDAO;
    private RoleDAO roleDAO;

    @Override
    public UserDAO getUserDAO() {
        if (userDAO == null) {
            userDAO = new UserDAOImpl(getConnection());
        }
        return userDAO;
    }

    @Override
    public ItemDAO getItemDAO() {
        if (itemDAO == null) {
            itemDAO = new ItemDAOImpl(getConnection());
        }
        return itemDAO;
    }

    @Override
    public OrderDAO getOrderDAO() {
        if (orderDAO == null) {
            orderDAO = new OrderDAOImpl(getConnection());
        }
        return orderDAO;
    }

    @Override
    public RoleDAO getRoleDAO() {
        if (roleDAO == null) {
            roleDAO = new RoleDAOImpl(getConnection());
        }
        return roleDAO;
    }

    static {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static Connection getConnection() {
        Connection connection = null;
        Context initCtx = null;
        try {
            initCtx = new InitialContext();
            Context envCtx = (Context) initCtx.lookup("java:comp/env");
            DataSource ds = (DataSource) envCtx.lookup("jdbc/mysql");
            connection = ds.getConnection();
        } catch (NamingException | SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return connection;
    }
}
```

**Example of DAO method**

```java
public Optional<User> findById(Long id) {
        User user = null;
        try (PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM shop.user WHERE id = ?", Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS)) {
            statement.setLong(1, id);
            ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery();
            resultSet.next();
            user = userMapper.map(resultSet);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return Optional.ofNullable(user);
    }
```

Comment: Hmmm... There's no easy way that I can think of but off the top of my head, you can use Interceptors powered by AspectJ. The interceptor will be responsible for managing and supplying connection instances that are used by the DAOs.

Comment: @FanaSithole I don't use Spring.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that, AspectJ is not Spring, Spring AOP is an equivalent of AspectJ

Comment: @FanaSithole will be better if I do it without any frameworks.

Comment: if you don't want frameworks, I'd suggest using a the Proxy pattern for your Data Access layer to do the same thing you would have done in an Aspect

Comment: Could you give a simplified example of a service? A single (public) service method should match one transaction, right?

Comment: @MickMnemonic for example It's user ordering. User adds item to the order, the item count decreases.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, you don't have to deal with transactions on DAO level. It's better to apply your transactions management at Service layer, because that allows you to control the logic on when you do/don't need a transaction and also control another aspects like rollback policies, etc.

In your case you may take a look into JTA documentation. This API provides annotations and other tools to manage your transactions in an easy way :)

Comment: So my problem is how to pass connection between DAOs.

Comment: @JohnDev, make your `DAOFactory` ignorant of connection-creation; move that part into the service layer (`getConnection()`) and _inject_ the `Connection` object into the `DAOFactory` _from the service_, not from the factory.

Comment: @MickMnemonic Is it normal if I will manage connection in my `DAOFactory`? For example, create methods for starting end closing transactions.

Comment: @JohnDev Maybe it would be fine to try using dependency injection by using the Java standard `@Inject` and `@Named` annotations, those are framework independent

Answer (score 0):

Now I've created class for managing a connection between all my DAOs. I've changed abstract class `DAOFactory` to interface and create abstract class `JdbcDaoFactory` and extends my `DaoManager` class.

**DAOFactory**

```java
public interface DAOFactory {

    UserDAO getUserDAO();
    ItemDAO getItemDAO();
    OrderDAO getOrderDAO();
    RoleDAO getRoleDAO();
}
```

```java
public abstract class JdbcDaoFactory implements DAOFactory {

    protected Connection connection;

    private UserDAO userDAO;
    private ItemDAO itemDAO;
    private OrderDAO orderDAO;
    private RoleDAO roleDAO;

    protected JdbcDaoFactory(Connection connection) {
        this.connection = connection;
    }

    @Override
    public UserDAO getUserDAO() {
        if (userDAO == null) {
            userDAO = new UserDAOImpl(connection);
        }
        return userDAO;
    }

    @Override
    public ItemDAO getItemDAO() {
        if (itemDAO == null) {
            itemDAO = new ItemDAOImpl(connection);
        }
        return itemDAO;
    }

    @Override
    public OrderDAO getOrderDAO() {
        if (orderDAO == null) {
            orderDAO = new OrderDAOImpl(connection);
        }
        return orderDAO;
    }

    @Override
    public RoleDAO getRoleDAO() {
        if (roleDAO == null) {
            roleDAO = new RoleDAOImpl(connection);
        }
        return roleDAO;
    }
}
```

```java
public class JdbcDaoManager extends JdbcDaoFactory implements AutoCloseable {

    public JdbcDaoManager() {
        super(DbHelper.getConnection());
    }

    public void beginTransaction() throws SQLException {
        connection.setAutoCommit(false);
    }

    public void commitTransaction() throws SQLException {
        connection.commit();
        connection.setAutoCommit(true);
    }

    public void rollbackTransaction() throws SQLException {
        connection.rollback();
        connection.setAutoCommit(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws SQLException {
        connection.close();
    }
}
```

But I'm still not sure how correct this solution is...
This is example of usage of that.

**With transaction**

```java
try (JdbcDaoManager daoManager = new JdbcDaoManager()) {
    try {
        daoManager.beginTransaction();
        daoManager.getUserDAO().insert(new User("user1", "12345"));
        daoManager.getUserDAO().insert(new User("user2", "12345"));
        daoManager.getUserDAO().insert(new User("user3", "12345"));
        daoManager.commitTransaction();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        daoManager.rollbackTransaction();
    }
} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**Without transactions**

```java
try (JdbcDaoManager daoManager = new JdbcDaoManager()) {
   daoManager.getUserDAO().insert(new User("user1", "12345"));
} catch (SQLException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```